# Zurb Foundation 6 - Orbit don't work

Tags: javascript, html, css, frameworks, zurb-foundation

I am using the Foundation Sites 6 Framework for one of my sites. I installed it via bower and included the css and js files in my html.
It all works fine but the orbit slider only shows the first two slides and then it stops. I don't get any errors in the console.

Here you can see the website: http://dev.epo-marketing.de/academy-studium-landingpage/

Header:

```
<!-- styles -->
  <!-- build:css _assets/css/styles.min.css -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="_assets/bower_components/foundation-sites/dist/css/foundation.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="_assets/fonts/kit-epo-academy-of-fine-art/css/embedded-woff.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="_assets/css/app.css">
  <!-- endbuild -->
<!-- /styles -->
```

Footer:

```
<!-- scripts -->
  <!-- build:js _assets/js/scripts.min.js -->
  <script type="text/javascript" src="_assets/bower_components/jquery/dist/jquery.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="_assets/bower_components/what-input/dist/what-input.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="_assets/bower_components/foundation-sites/dist/js/foundation.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="_assets/js/app.js"></script>
  <!-- endbuild -->
  <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=API_KEY&callback=initMap" async defer></script>
<!-- /scripts -->
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it by myself. I had to include the motion-ui javascript and css files.